# How to efficiently split file into arbitrary byteranges in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to upload a big file to a third party service.
This third party service gives me a list of urls and byteranges:

```
requests = [
  {url: "https://.../part1", from: 0, to: 20_000_000},
  {url: "https://.../part2", from: 20_000_001, to: 40_000_000},
  {url: "https://.../part3", from: 40_000_001, to: 54_184_279}
]
```

I'm using the [httpx gem](https://honeyryderchuck.gitlab.io/httpx/) to upload the data, the `:body` option can receive an `IO` or `Enumerable` object.
I would like to split and upload chunks in an efficient way. This is why I think I should avoid writing chunks to the disks and also avoid loading the entire file into memory. I suppose that the best option would be some kind of "lazy Enumerable" but I dont know how to write the `part` function that would return this `IO` or `Enumerable` object.

```
file = File.open("bigFile", "rb")
results = requests.each do |request|
   Thread.start { HTTPX.post(request[:url]), body: part(file, request[:from], request[:to]) }
end.map(&:value)

def part(file, from, to)
   # ???
end
```

Comment: cant you use an IO object with `seek` to "fast forward" to the start of the current chunk?

Comment: Probably, but I think I will need multiple descriptors or cursors in order to read chunks concurrently and I also should be able to stop the IO object from reading after the end of each byterange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to generate an enumerator for each "byterange" would be to let the `part` function handle the opening of the file:

```rb
def part(filepath, from, to = nil, chunk_size = 4096, &block)
  return to_enum(__method__, filepath, from, to, chunk_size) unless block_given?
  size = File.size(filepath)
  to = size-1 unless to and to >= from and to < size
  io = File.open(filepath, "rb")
  io.seek(from, IO::SEEK_SET)
  while (io.pos <= to)
    size = (io.pos + chunk_size <= to) ? chunk_size : 1 + to - io.pos
    chunk = io.read(size)
    yield chunk
  end
ensure
  io.close if io
end
```

<s>***Warning**: the chunk size calculation may be wrong, I will check it in a while (I have to take care of my child)*</s>

**Note**: You may want to improve this function to ensure that you always read a full physical HDD block (or a multiple of it), as it will greatly speed-up the IO. *You'll have a misalignment when `from` is not a multiple of the physical HDD block.*

The `part` function now returns an `Enumerator` when called without a block:

```rb
part("bigFile", 0, 1300, 512)
#=> #<Enumerator: main:part("bigFile", 0, 1300, 512)
```

And of course you can call it directly with a block:

```rb
part("bigFile", 0, 1300, 512) do |chunk|
  puts "#{chunk.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You pointed me in the right direction.
Don't worry about the `size` calculation, I will check it :)

Comment: You're welcome. I recently needed to generate a custom Enumerator for big files but I didn't find any explicit example. It turns out to be simple, but it's not that easy to figure out how to do it. PS, there really was an error in the calculation of the chunk size.

Answer (score 0):

```
IO.read("bigFile", 1000, 2000)
```

will read 1000 bytes, starting at offset 2000. Ruby starts counting at zero, so I think

```
IO.read("bigFile", 20_000_000, 0) #followed by
IO.read("bigFile,20_000_000,20_000_000) #not 20_000_001
```

would be correct. Without bookkeeping:

```
f = File.open("bigFile")
partname = "part0"
until f.eof? do
  partname = partname.succ
  chunk = f.read(20_000_000)

  #do something with chunk and partname
end
f.close
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nevertheless I think that `IO.read("bigFile", 0, 20_000_000)` loads the entire chunk in memory and I would like to avoid that if the chunk is big. Or is `IO.read` lazy?

Comment: Yes, the chunk is read in memory, but not written disk. The entire file is not read in memory.

Comment: @steenslag, user1277186 is firing a thread by chunk, so that would most probably end up with all the chunks loaded in RAM at the same time, doesn't it ?